# psql giving bogus errors

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-dump

when I run a script using psql using either the -f option or redirecting input I get bogus error messages.

The file was generated with pg_dump,using the "-F p" option, which creates a sql file.

*Dumps can be output in script or archive file formats. Script dumps are plain-text files containing the SQL commands required to reconstruct the database to the state it was in at the time it was saved. To restore from such a script, feed it to psql. Script files can be used to reconstruct the database even on other machines and other architectures; with some modifications, even on other SQL database products.*

A **fragment** of this sql file is:

```
 -- Name: customer_info customer_info_pkey; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema:
   public; Owner: javautil

   ALTER TABLE ONLY public.customer_info
       ADD CONSTRAINT customer_info_pkey PRIMARY KEY (customer_info_id);

 -- Name: customer customer_pkey; Type: CONSTRAINT; Schema: public;
   Owner: javautil

   ALTER TABLE ONLY public.customer
       ADD CONSTRAINT customer_pkey PRIMARY KEY (customer_id);
```

I get the following error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE ONLY public.customer_info
                                         ^ 
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ADD"
LINE 1: ADD CONSTRAINT customer_info_pkey PRIMARY KEY (customer_info...
    ^
ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE ONLY public.customer
                                    ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ADD"
LINE 1: ADD CONSTRAINT customer_pkey PRIMARY KEY (customer_id);
```

Comment: these sql statements look legit , I assume this is part of bigger sql file

Comment: It was, you are correct it generated "--" statements and I have editted my question to reflect that.  Before, the markdown was making it bold with -- so I then wrapped in ```
but somehow stripped a leading "-"

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to run the output from `pg_dump` as a standard SQL script. In order to use files generated by `pg_dump`, they need to be used in conjunction with `pg_restore`, the documentation for which is [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/app-pgrestore.html).

Essentially, the format of files created by `pg_dump` is special, to allow `pg_restore` to be selective about what it restores to the database or output.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my post to reflect the fact that this was created with the -F p option, which creates a sql script, which to my understanding, should be able to be run with psql.

It sure looks like standard sql.

Comment: A dump generated without the `-F` parameter (or with `-F p`)  is absolutely intended to be restored with `psql`

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this file has had newlines mangled somehow, and psql is misinterpreting where the line ends are.  Notice that it first sends a command with `ALTER TABLE ONLY public.customer` and you get a complaint that the command ends there (which makes sense: that command is incomplete); and then it sends another command `ADD CONSTRAINT ...` and you get a complaint about that.

I wonder if you're filtering the file through a pipe, or something like that, that puts an EOF at each line end.  We would need to see the full commands that produce and consume the backup file, and more about the environment where those commands run, to be certain.